# Number of combinations in a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Given the size of a matrix is $N \times N$, how many unique matrices are there given the following restrictions:

- Matrix entries can only contain numbers $\left[0,b\right]$
- A valid matrix cannot have more than $\frac{(N \times N)}{b}$ elements of one kind
- The result of $\frac{(N \times N)}{b}$ is always an integer
- The number of elements of one kind cannot be odd (must be even)
- Elements of one kind must always have another element of the same kind in their vicinity (only north, east, south and west, no diagonals)
- If 2 elements that find themselves in each other's vicinity are to be removed from the matrix, the above rule must still hold true.

Wanted to go to sleep and started thinking about this. Haven't gotten far, this is why It'll be nice if someone help me ( a lot :) )

Comment: None?  If you have $N^2$ cells in your table, but only $N/b \cdot (b+1)$ elements to fill them, then you have no table.

Comment: My mistake. That was meant to be N^2/b elements of one kind

Comment: You want $[1, b]$.  The number of elements in an integer range $[a, b]$ is $b - a + 1$.